# How to test methods that download big files

Tags: java, junit

Usually I have these methods responsible for downloading large file/s to a local directory.

It annoys me because I don't really know how to test that *properly*?

Should I run a test case that downloads these files to a temp directory using `Role` in Junit? Or maybe ask it to download files to the same local directory in production?

Importantly, such method takes a long time to download 1GB+ file, so is it bad that a test case would take a long time?

What would be an ideal test case for this?

```
public File downloadFile(File dir, URL url){
   //url contains a 1GB or more
   //method takes a long time
   return file; // it's located in dir
}
```

Comment: It is strange enough that this method does not even throw an exception on failure. And anyway, what is it that you want to do? Unit tests or integration tests? Finally, please note that this is 2016; you should not use File anymore, but Path and Files

Comment: @fge, well, I meant to make it a simple example. Sorry, I didn't know that File is dead now. I want to test if this method works well without waiting for a long time.

Comment: Can you define "works well"? What is it that you want exactly? Do you want to test the behavior of your program if this method happens to fail?

Comment: I want to test if this method works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My belief here is that you are approaching the problem in the wrong way altogether.

You want to test "if that method works". But this method is highly dependent on "side effects" which are, in this case, failures which can occur at any of these steps:

- connection failure: the given URL cannot be accessed (for whatever reason);
- network failure: connection is cut while the transfer was in progress;
- file system failure: the specified file cannot be created/opened in write mode; or the write fails while you are downloading contents.

In short: it is impossible to test whether the method "works". And what is more, due to the amount of possible failures mentioned above, it means that your method should *at least* throw an exception so that the caller of the method can deal with it.

Finally, this is 2016; it is assumed below that you use Java 7 or later, but here is how you can rewrite your method:

```
public Path downloadFile(final Path dir, final URL url)
    throws IOException
{
    final String filename = /* decide about the filename here */;
    final Path ret = dir.resolve(filename);

    try (
        final InputStream in = url.openStream();
    ) {
        Files.copy(in, ret);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Now, in your tests, just mock the behavior of that method; make it fail, make it return a valid path, make the URL fail on `.openStream()`... You can simulate the behavior of that method whichever way you want so that you can test how the *callers* of this method behave.

But such a method, in itself, is just too dependent on "side effects" that it cannot be tested reliably.